# Pseudo Roman Cipher

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, grid-deduction, rebus

A while ago, I made this puzzle and gave it to my friend. But his comment was not so good. "This looks fine except it's not realistic", he said. I know he is smart but ... :( I don't want to believe that.
Anyway, what do you think about this puzzle?

[image: Image-Pseudo Roman Cipher]

Comment: In case it is not obvious, the story was created by me; he's an imaginary friend ; P .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Step 1

Fill in the blank cells in the grid with:

> `..VII`
>  `IV.IV`
>  `.V...`
>  `VIV.V`
>  `III.V`

where the letters are

> the Roman numerals for the numbers indicated by the dots around the edges.

## Step 2

Breaking up the grid's contents (including the X's and circle in the original image) along the darker black lines gives:

> XX VIII V XIV XV ⚬ XXVI V XVIII XV

or

> 20 8 5 14 15 ⚬ 26 5 18 15

Interpreting these as letter positions within the alphabet (and treating the middle circle as separator punctuation), this decodes to

> THE NO. ZERO

## The title

"Cipher" is:

> used with a double meaning: a method of encoding text, and as the number 0.  (Both "cipher" and "zero" are derived from the Arabic word *sifr*.)

It's "Roman" because

> It relies on Roman numerals.

But "pseudo" because the ancient Romans

> did not have a symbol or word for the number zero, and [did not use our modern 26-letter alphabet.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mC0wsuowbRA)

Comment: @ACB: OK, have I got it now?

Comment: Correct! Well done :)

Comment: Rot13(Va nqqvgvba gb gur ernfba lbh tnir sbe pubbfvat gur jbeq 'cfrhqb' V gubhtug vg jvyy uryc fbyiref gb erzvaq bs 'bhgfvqr (fhqb)xh' (nygubhtu guvf vf abg n fhqbxh chmmyr, yvxr va [guvf](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/117507/78877) erprag cbfg) gb znxr frafr bs gur qbgf bhgfvqr gur tevq. Ohg V qba'g xabj vs vg urycrq lbh. Gvgyr jnf gur xrl :) )

Comment: Your last spoiler also describes my friend's comment.